# How do I know which is the positive root for this quadratic?

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following function:

```
f[i_] := ((β σ i + (ϵ + 
         q1 μ) + σ (ρ + 
          q2 μ))/((ρ + μ + β i) (μ + \
ϵ + β σ i) - ρ ϵ)) - (((μ + \
γ) (μ + α))/(β γ μ A));
```

I solved it using:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[((β σ i + (ϵ + 
          q1 μ) + σ (ρ + 
           q2 μ))/((ρ + μ + β i) (μ + \
ϵ + β σ i) - ρ ϵ)) - (((μ + \
γ) (μ + α))/(β γ μ A)) == 0, i]]
```

Giving the two roots:

```
{{i -> 1/(
    2 β^2 (α + μ) (γ + μ) σ) (A \
β^2 γ μ σ - β (α + μ) (\
γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + (μ + ρ) σ) + \
√(β^2 (-4 μ (α + μ) (γ + μ) \
σ (α (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ) + \
μ (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ) - 
              A β γ (ϵ + q1 μ + 
                 q2 μ σ + ρ σ)) + (μ (\
γ + μ) (ϵ + μ) + μ (-A β γ + \
(γ + μ) (μ + ρ)) σ + α (γ + \
μ) (ϵ + μ + (μ + ρ) σ))^2)))}, {i -> \
-1/(2 β^2 (α + μ) (γ + μ) σ) (-A \
β^2 γ μ σ + β (α + μ) (\
γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + (μ + ρ) σ) + \
√(β^2 (-4 μ (α + μ) (γ + μ) \
σ (α (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ) + \
μ (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ) - 
               A β γ (ϵ + q1 μ + 
                  q2 μ σ + ρ σ)) + (μ (\
γ + μ) (ϵ + μ) + μ (-A β γ + \
(γ + μ) (μ + ρ)) σ + α (γ + \
μ) (ϵ + μ + (μ + ρ) σ))^2)))}}
```

However, how can I know which is the positive root?

All parameteres are postive with $q_1+q_2=1$.

**EDIT**
As per yarchik's comment, here is the paper, page 2166 in the journal:

https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1468121810003408?token=3943EADB69630D535D3FC9789D2A93FDB7322523BD8AA64A9FCDA4A247F05913CA2C0BA747CADE5337E62EA412B678D5&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220120122026

**EDIT 2**

Attempting Bob Hanlon's solution to the following function doesn't give me a solution, can someone check that it indeed gives a solution?

```
f[i_] := 1/(
   b2 b5 (b1 + i \[Beta]) \[Epsilon]2 (\[Mu] + i \[Beta] \[Sigma]))
    i (-b1 (b2 b3 (b4 b5 - 
           a3 q3 \[Gamma] \[Delta]) - \[Gamma] (b2 b5 q2 + 
           a2 b2 q3 \[Delta] + b5 q1 \[Epsilon]1 + 
           a1 q3 \[Delta] \[Epsilon]1) \[Epsilon]2) (\[Mu] + 
        i \[Beta] \[Sigma]) + \[Beta] (\[Epsilon]1 \[Epsilon]2 (i \
\[Gamma] (b5 q1 + a1 q3 \[Delta]) (\[Mu] + i \[Beta] \[Sigma]) + 
           A b5 (p \[Mu] + f r \[Sigma] + i p \[Beta] \[Sigma])) + 
        b2 (-b3 i (b4 b5 - a3 q3 \[Gamma] \[Delta]) (\[Mu] + 
              i \[Beta] \[Sigma]) + 
           i \[Gamma] (b5 q2 + a2 q3 \[Delta]) \[Epsilon]2 (\[Mu] + 
              i \[Beta] \[Sigma]) + 
           A b5 \[Epsilon]2 (\[Mu] - 
              p \[Mu] + (f - f r + i \[Beta] - 
                 i p \[Beta]) \[Sigma]))));

$Assumptions = 
  q1 + q2 + q3 == 1 && a1 + a2 + a3 == 1 && And @@ Thread[{
       A, \[Beta], \[Mu], p, k, c, \[Sigma], a1, a2, a3, \[Delta], q1,
        q2, q3, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, 
       f, \[Epsilon]1, \[Epsilon]2, \[Gamma]} > 0];
sol = Solve[{f[i] == 0, i > 0}, i, Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: @yarchik i will attach a paper where they say a positive root exits..

Comment: I just noticed that all parameters are positive. Therefore I deleted my comments.

Comment: Reason I ask is because I am doing computations further down which  requires the positive root. Okay, now is it possible to know the positive root?

Comment: `CoefficientList[Numerator[Together[-f[i]]], i] // Factor` will show that for `A` sufficiently small, all coefficients are positive. In this situation there cannot be a positive solution to the quadratic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau in the paper it says for $R_0 >1$ there exits a unique positive root in the interval $(0, A)$

Comment: I'm not able to check this since the paper is behind a paywall. But those coefficients make this look unpromising, unless there are further conditions that prevent `A` from being too small relative to the other parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[i_] := ((β σ i + (ϵ + q1 μ) + σ (ρ + q2 μ))/((ρ + μ + β i) 
  (μ + ϵ + β σ i) - ρ ϵ)) - (((μ + γ) (μ + α))/(β γ μ A));
```

Tell Mathematica what you know about constraints

```
$Assumptions = q1 + q2 == 1 && And @@
    Thread[{A, q1, q2, α, β, γ, ϵ, μ, ρ, σ} > 0];
```

If you want a positive root, constrain the root to being positive

```
sol = Solve[{f[i] == 0, i > 0}, i,
   Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

The condition is

```
sol[[1, 1, -1, -1]]

(* β > ((α + μ) (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ))/(A γ (ϵ + μ - q2 μ + 
    q2 μ σ + ρ σ)) *)
```

Comment: +1. You have seen the heart of the problem.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon exactly what I wanted. thank you very much.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon the last part where you wrote `sol[[1, 1, -1, -1]]

(* β > ((α + μ) (γ + μ) (ϵ + μ + ρ))/(A γ (ϵ + μ - q2 μ + 
    q2 μ σ + ρ σ)) *)` why did you do this? This is exactly correct since that condition is the reproduction number for this ODE system. That condition; $R_0>1$ is right but im unsure why you entered `sol[[1, 1, -1, -1]]`

Comment: @Math - `sol[[1, 1, -1, -1]]` extracts the condition out of the `ConditionalExpression` given in `sol`. `sol` is a list of length `1`.  The first index to `Part` removes the outer `List` brackets; the second index extracts the `Rule`; the third index extracts the RHS of the `Rule`, i.e., the `ConditionalExpression`; and the last index extracts the condition from the `ConditionalExpression`. `sol//InputForm` will show the explicit `ConditionalExpression`. `sol//Normal` will show the root without the condition necessary to make the root positive.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you very much.  I tried this same procedure with another function for a different but similar system but it doesn't give a solution, why? I have the roots but I want to double check solving using your proposed method. I will edit it in the question as an addendum.

Comment: @Math - It is impossible to say without knowing what the system is. Post a new question showing what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: @BobHanlon here is the new question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263345/how-do-i-know-which-is-the-positive-root-for-this-quadratic-cont