# How do I know which is the positive root for this quadratic (cont)?

Tags: equation-solving

I used Bob Hanlon's solution from here:
[How do I know which is the positive root for this quadratic?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263277/how-do-i-know-which-is-the-positive-root-for-this-quadratic/263285?noredirect=1#comment656031_263285)

or the following function but it outputs nothing, not even an empty set. It shows its been run but nothing outputs, why?

```
f[i_] := 1/(
   b2 b5 (b1 + i β) ϵ2 (μ + i β σ))
    i (-b1 (b2 b3 (b4 b5 - 
           a3 q3 γ δ) - γ (b2 b5 q2 + 
           a2 b2 q3 δ + b5 q1 ϵ1 + 
           a1 q3 δ ϵ1) ϵ2) (μ + 
        i β σ) + β (ϵ1 ϵ2 (i \
γ (b5 q1 + a1 q3 δ) (μ + i β σ) + 
           A b5 (p μ + f r σ + i p β σ)) + 
        b2 (-b3 i (b4 b5 - a3 q3 γ δ) (μ + 
              i β σ) + 
           i γ (b5 q2 + a2 q3 δ) ϵ2 (μ + 
              i β σ) + 
           A b5 ϵ2 (μ - 
              p μ + (f - f r + i β - 
                 i p β) σ))));

$Assumptions = 
  q1 + q2 + q3 == 1 && a1 + a2 + a3 == 1 && And @@ Thread[{
       A, β, μ, p, r,σ, a1, a2, a3, δ, q1,
        q2, q3, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, 
       f, ϵ1, ϵ2, γ} > 0];
sol = Solve[{f[i] == 0, i > 0}, i, Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: This evaluates for longer than I am willing to wait. Perhaps it timed out on your system.

Comment: Both `Solve` and `FullSimplify` can be very time consuming. Rather than putting both calculations in the same evaluation, split this into two steps. Won't necessarily work, but this is the recommended approach.

Comment: Sometimes doing Algebra I yourself is more efficient that figuring out how to get *Mma* to do it. Get the coefficients $a,b,c$ of your quadratic factor and plug them into the output of `LogicalExpand@Reduce[(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a) > 0, {a, b, c}]`, which gives three cases for the greater root `(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)` to be positive. Check the lesser root similarly, if desired. Reducing the conditions to something intelligible may be beyond the powers of human and machine, but one might try anyway.

Comment: BTW, using `f` both as an undefined parameter and a defined function, while seeming not to cause trouble here, is still asking for trouble. It would be better to use a longer name for `f[i]`, for instance.